# What's the purpose of ANDing a bit mask with all bits set to a value?

Tags: logic

I'm adapting an algorithm for calculating a CRC 16-bit CCITT (XModem) value from an ASCII input.  I've found some code [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c6975d0a-4be3-46f1-ae4b-9b27f1ce0049/xmodem-crcccitt-with-hex-input?forum=vbgeneral). I'm using the function the poster has in his question, but I've noticed at the bottom he does this:

```
calcrc = crc And &HFFFF
```

What's the purpose of applying such a bit mask that is all 1s to a value?  Doesn't that just return the value again?

Comment: It could be because the code is mechanically generated from a template. It could be there also because some situation require changing it, and having it in place make it easy to make sure the masking is done at the right place. I have done that on occasion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is crc that it's calculating is defined to be a 16-bit value, the `And &HFFFF` will truncate the most significant bit outside the 16-bit range if there is any overflow during the calculation.